# GeoPandas intersect not working as expected

Tags: python, intersection, geopandas

Using GeoPandas 0.4.0 with Python 3.5, I'm finding that geopandas.intersects does not behave as I expect it to. For example, a buffer around Switzerland does not appear to intersect with neighbouring countries.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gp

>>> world = gp.read_file(gp.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
>>> eur = world.loc[world['name'].isin(['Switzerland','Austria', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Slovenia']),  ]
>>> ch = world.loc[world['name'] == 'Switzerland', ]
>>> buff = ch.buffer(1)

>>> eur.intersects(buff)
9      False
28      True
41     False
79     False
150    False
dtype: bool
```

Ie, the buffer only intersects with index 28 from eur, which is Switzerland. But the buffer clearly overlaps with the other countries as well, as demonstrated when plotting:

```
>>> fig, ax= plt.subplots()
>>> ax.set_aspect('equal')
>>> eur.plot(ax=ax)
>>> buff.plot(ax=ax, color='red'
```

[image: Buffer around Switzerland]

What am I doing wrong that's preventing me from seeing the buffer intersecting with the other countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersects predicate is for GeoSeries and is elementwise  thus with all the lines/polygons in eur

```
print(eur.index)
Int64Index([9, 28, 41, 79, 150], dtype='int64')
for i in eur.index:
    print(i,"-->", buff.intersects(eur.loc[i].geometry))
9 --> 28    True
28 --> 28    True
41 --> 28    True
79 --> 28    True
150 --> 28    False
```

With two GeoDataFrames use [overlay](http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html)

```
buffer = gp.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':buff})
result = gp.overlay(buffer,eur, how='intersection')
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll use overlay, since I'll be working with 2 geodataframes.